# Any way to trace when «учёный» became a noun?

Tags: история-языка, словоупотребление

I need to know the approximate time **учёный** was substantivised.

Dahl has no separate entry for the word as either noun *or* adjective, but he does use it as a noun when defining other terms (e.g. *«учоный, этимъ предметомъ занимающійся»*).

The Russian corpus gave me identical-looking timelines for [all instances](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F3%F7%E5%ED%FB%E9&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) and [adjectival instances](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F3%F7%E5%ED%FB%E9&gramm1=A&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) of **ученый**, and only a slightly different one for [substantival instances](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F3%F7%E5%ED%FB%E9&gramm1=S&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=20#toggle). I have no idea how reliable these are.

Trying to find a direct answer doesn't lead anywhere. I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: this is likely a shred of the collocation **ученый мужъ**, perhaps some chronological hints could be obtained from comparison between the stats of decline in its frequency and those of rise in frequency of **учёный** by itself

Comment: _учёный_, as any other adjective, has been used as a noun since time immemorial, the same way _слепой_ or _толстый_ are. The difference is that by now _учёный_ has fallen out of use as a participle or adjective: you can't really say _учёный математике_ or _хорошо учёный_ without sounding archaic. Did you mean to ask when did that happen?

Comment: @Quassnoi It's for a translation where I have to adapt, rather than explain, any English-specific bits. A factoid comes up that the English word "scientist" has only been in use since the 1830s. I must either match it by dating the modern use of "ученый" in Russian or, failing that, drop it altogether.

Comment: @nikolayershov: I doubt you can make it work with _учёный_. There's probably a chance of pinpointing the use of _образование_ (in the sense of "education") around late XVIII, not sure how would it fit with your goal though.

Comment: my assumption was incorrect, judging by Google corpus **учёный мужъ** in Nominative is a collocation of extremely low frequency, the earliest source listed there in which **учёный** is used substantively is from [1760](http://goo.gl/iSfbRs) in the first Russian journal of popular science "Ежемесячные сочинения и известия о ученых делах" founded in 1755, which i guess is a good starting point since this is when science began to be understood in Russia in the modern sense with application of the word **наука** in the corresponding meaning ["из высоких наук"](http://goo.gl/oksoug)

Comment: "Scientist " came into use as a person occupied professionally with science in the first half of the nineteenth century. But "ученый" is obviously older, because it initially possessed another meaning "знающий, наученный"a person, who knows a lot. But it got to be used in the meaning of "scientist "at the same time with the development of science in the country. So,  what's the use to know the time of субстантивации?

Comment: From the RNC: "Художники и **ученые** истощеваются от трудов, чтобы что изящное соделать, и имена свои при сочинениях своих полагают." [М. М. Щербатов. Разговор о бессмертии души (**1788**)] or "Будучи как француженка жива и под старость, она имела около себя круг иностранный; актеры, художники, **ученые** к ней съезжались, и всякий день на детской половине был для них особый стол." [И. М. Долгоруков. Повесть о рождении моем, происхождении и всей моей жизни, писанная мной самим и начатая в Москве, 1788-го года в августе месяце, на 25-ом году моей жизни / Части 1-2 (1788-1822)]

Comment: I would suggest that this word was created around the same time as schools and Christianity were introduced - around 988 (accordingly to this article: [История образования: от первых школ Руси до советских](https://www.culture.ru/materials/253541/istoriya-obrazovaniya-ot-pervykh-shkol-rusi-do-sovetskikh). For me it seems like it was first used as a "person who can read" or "person who was studied". That is why it has a grammatical case.

Comment: The form (adj + noun) often becomes only a one word - adjective that became a noun. For example, "выпускной бал". Not very long time ago it was "выпускной бал", but everybody says just "выпускной" at the moment. Where did "бал" go? Nobody knows, it is just an easier way to say "выпускной" and everybody does so.
I think the point is nobody knows exactly when it happened, words just change or become extinctive by the time.
If you need the answer very much, someone needs to track the word down in all official documents since.. like.. 1721 or somewhat. Great job, doesnt worth it

Comment: Оно может быть существительным, когда используется само по себе, а может быть прилагательным, если используется в выражении "учёный человек".

Answer (score 1):

"**научный деятель**" is still used to mean a *science worker*, or someone who is professionally employed, or widely recognized, as an active contributor to scientific research.

But to answer the question how to trace how the word became used instead of a phrase, the best tool to use is probably Google's ngrams.

[Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%8A%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%8A%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) a graph of use of "ученый мужъ" vs "ученый деятель" vs "научный деятель".

You can graph other combinations to see which words became used instead of others.

[It looks like](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%8A%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%2C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%8A%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%8A%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)  "ученый мужъ" made a brief appearance in 1788-1793, but its use was eclipsed by the simple "ученый".  While "научный деятель" came into use in 1889.

Although if you use the modern spelling, "ученый муж", you can [surprisingly find *earlier* periods](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=36&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)  of high correlation between "ученый муж" and "ученый".  This maybe due to the Google scanning modern publications of early Russian books (which use modernized spelling).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there will be any definitive answer to this. It is occasionally used as an adjective "учёный специалист", "учёный секретарь", but predominantly is used as a noun, and has been so seemingly always. You are looking hundreds of years ago, plus minus hundreds of years for the uncertainty

Comment: this does not answer the question - you basically say you don't know.

Answer (score -2):

На русском языке есть два слова - омонимы, ученый(прилагательное) и ученый(существительное). Можно говорить, к примеру, "великий ученый Ломоносов сделал монжество открытий"(где ученый существительное), а можно: "Че умный такой, ученый человечек? (где ученый прилагательное). Таких слов в русском очень много. Вожатый - предводитель группы(сущ), вожатый человек(прил).
Вообще я русский, мой родной язык русский, и я надеюсь помочь Вам, англичанам, в изучении этого прекрасного, красивого языка!

Comment: вы не ответили на вопрос - вопрос о том когда слово "учёный" стало использоваться как существительное - и не все, кто здесь задают вопросы англичане или неносители языка.

Comment: Автор вопроса — Николай Ершов. Вы можете щелкнуть по имени этого пользователя и почитать его ОТВЕТЫ  на вопросы "всяких разных англичан" о русском языке

Answer (score -3):

History of this word is closly connected to history of science in Russia.

The first "true scientist" in Russia was Lomonosov (1711-1765, scientific activity strated at 1740).

The Russian Academy of Science was established by Peter I in 1724.

This are good reference dates to start with. I believe that Peter I was the man who introduced this word.

Comment: this does not answer the question.

Comment: Strange. Man asked : "I need to know the approximate time учёный was substantivised?". I've gave an approximate time (with some justifications). Why it is not an answer?

Comment: In the question the word "time" refers to an occasion, circumstance, or event. For example, if I ask you "Do you remember that time I crashed my car into a tree?" I am not asking you to remember the date, I am asking you to recall the incident. An answer to this question should explain the circumstances under which this term was coined.